# Not able to instantiate adapter wrapper because of generics in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am not able to pass my adapter to adapter wrapper class because of generics. Here is how i am instantiating it

```
val a = MyAdapter()
val b = AdAdapter(a)
```

This code results in an error

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is MyAdapter but RecyclerView.Adapter
<in RecyclerView.ViewHolder> was expected
```

Here is my adapter

```
class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.VH>() {

    //Some Code Here

    class VH(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

}
```

Here is the Adadapter

```
class AdAdapter(private val originalAdapter: 
                      RecyclerView.Adapter<in RecyclerView.ViewHolder>)
                      : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    //Some Code

}
```

Comment: please add a comment if you are downvoting. will be happy to explain/edit

Answer (score 0):

As explained in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections,

> `Array<in String>` corresponds to Java's `Array<? super String>`, i.e. you can pass an array of `CharSequence` or an array of `Object` to the `fill()` function.

So in your case you need `MyAdapter` to be a `RecyclerView.Adapter<? super RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` and it isn't, because `MyAdapter.VH` doesn't satisfy the constraint.

Comment: if i use out in place of in. i can not call onbindviewholder on this adapter

Comment: You could just make `AdAdapter` generic as well.